# How to find nested elements in native android and java

Tags: java, android, selenium

I'm struggling to find nested element for the following in my native android and want to know how is best to retrieve them:

[image]

My code which is unable to find the elements:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='password_complexity_layout']//*[@id='textView']")
public WebElement textView1;

@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='password_complexity_layout']//*[@id='textView2']")
public WebElement textView2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below piece of code to find all the views.

```
LinearLayout ll = …
final int childCount = ll.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
      View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
      // Do something with v.
      // …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were close. You can try the following *xpath* solution:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.LinearLayout[contains(@resource-id, 'password_complexity_layout')]//android.widget.TextView[contains(@id, 'textView')]")
public WebElement textView1;

@FindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.LinearLayout[contains(@resource-id, 'password_complexity_layout')]//android.widget.TextView[contains(@id, 'textView2')]")
public WebElement textView2;
```